# Print to a different printer if the default one is offline

Tags: cups

I want to setup CUPS to print to a second printer if the default printer is offline for some reason.  I have searched but I think my terminology for what I want is not right so not getting far.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set up a printer class that contains a group of printers.  It will print in the order of which they are listed in the class.  If one is not available it will move to the next.

http://www.packtpub.com/article/cups-how-to-manage-multiple-printers

Pretty good article explaining the process.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! While the link answers the question nicely, it's useless if the site ever goes down; therefore, summarize the instructions on the webpage, and link to the page for attribution